# Lucene migration text field difference in 3.0.3 and 5

Tags: java, lucene, migration

I have a problem with the migration of a Lucene field from version 3.0.3 to 5.x . I prepared two JUnit test programs (one with 3.0.3 and other with 5.x) to compare the behavior.

Lucene 3:

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, analyzer, true, MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
....
Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new Field("keyword", "another test@foo-bar", Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.ANALYZED));
indexWriter.addDocument(doc);
indexWriter.commit();
....

indexReader = IndexReader.open(FSDirectory.open(path.toFile()), false);
searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "keyword", analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse("test");
searcher.search(query, searcher.maxDoc());
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, searcher.maxDoc());
ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
doc = indexReader.document(hits[0].doc);
// doc is now NULL <- EXPECTED
assertNull(result);
```

The similar test with Lucene 5.x (only changed code lines):

```
analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig indexConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
            .setCommitOnClose(true).setOpenMode(openMode);
// create the index writer
indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, indexConfig);
...
// line old style (Lucene 3)
doc.add(new Field("keyword", "another test@foo-bar", Field.Store.YES,
            Field.Index.ANALYZED));
// or with new field types (enable only one line)
doc.add(new TextField("keyword", "another test@foo-bar", Field.Store.YES));
...
Query query = new QueryParser(field, analyzer).parse(field + ":"
                + value);
doc = indexReader.document(hits[0].doc);
// returns a document each time
assertNull(doc); // fails!
```

I used the following migration document https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/MIGRATE.html to replace the Field class with the TextField class.  But the search works different.

Question: How can I create the same result with the new Lucene 5.x as before with Lucene 3?

The Lucene 3 analyzer seems to split the input string on spaces only. The Lucene 5 version of the analyzer seems to split on space, '@' and '-'. :/

Comment: `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.ClassicAnalyzer` seems to match the old Lucene 3 behavior.